# Two Queries? "if($_GET['data'])"

Tags: php

What is wrong?

```
if($_GET['data']) && ($_GET['kullaniciadi'])  {
print '--''; }
else
print '--';
```

two is not possible to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed up your parentheses. Try this:

```
if($_GET['data'] && $_GET['kullaniciadi']) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

The parentheses are for the `if` statement, not each condition. The conditions to be evaluated go inside. In your case you have 2 conditions, and the `if` will execute if both are evaluated to `true`.

If you do need to put the conditions inside parentheses too, make sure they balance:

```
if(($_GET['data']) && ($_GET['kullaniciadi'])) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Also note that by changing that in your code above, it still won't work. You have an extra single quote in the `print` of your `if` block. Change it to be the same as the one in your `else` block.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You messed up your brackets.Try:

```
if($_GET['data'] && $_GET['kullaniciadi'])  
{
    print '--'; 
}
else
{
    print '--';
}
```

I also changed the first `print` statement, as you had a superfluous single quote in there.

Answer (score 0):

if(($_GET['data']) && ($_GET['kullaniciadi']))  {

in php, the format is such :

if (condition) {

now you're having 
if (condition) && (condition) {

whereby it would read as

if (condition) and then expecting a '{' when you're giving a '&' hence the error